# Как функцию заставить ждать, пока не выполнится работа в окне - Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Имеется такой код:

```
bool Auth(int num)
{
Authentication AuthWindow;
AuthWindow.show();
if(AuthWindow.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
{
    string login=AuthWindow.login,password=AuthWindow.password;
    if(!TryLogin(login,password))
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    AuthWindow.close();
    user(login, password);
    }else exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    return true;
}
```

Конечно же он не работает.
Как заставить функцию ждать, пока окно авторизации не завершит свою работу?

Comment: Необходимо чтоб ``authentication `` был наследником от QDialog, у которого нужно вызывать метод QDialog::exec()

Comment: Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: @Александр, но как вернутся?

Comment: Так возможно TryLogin возвращает false, и сразу происходит выход из программы? Воспользуйтесь отладчиком

Comment: Ах, благодарю. Сервер, который должен обрабатывать соединения - упал :/
Всё работает. Спасибо

Comment: @Александр, с Вами как-нибудь можно связаться?

Comment: В профиле есть мой скайп

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Необходимо чтоб authentication был наследником от `QDialog`, у которого нужно вызывать блокирующий метод `QDialog::exec()`. Совет на другую тему, в C++ обычно принято название классов писать с большой буквы, а название переменных с маленькой, я этого буду придерживаться в своем примере.
Пример возможного класса `Authentication`:

`authentication.h`

```
#ifndef AUTHENTICATION_H
#define AUTHENTICATION_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class Authentication;
}

class Authentication : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Authentication(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Authentication();

    bool getAuthenticated() const;

private slots:
    void on_closeButton_clicked();
    void on_applyButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::Authentication *ui;
};

#endif // AUTHENTICATION_H
```

`authentication.cpp`

```
#include "authentication.h"
#include "ui_authentication.h"

Authentication::Authentication(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Authentication)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Authentication::~Authentication()
{
    delete ui;
}

bool Authentication::getAuthenticated() const
{
    return ui->checkBox->isChecked();
}

void Authentication::on_closeButton_clicked()
{
    reject();
}

void Authentication::on_applyButton_clicked()
{
    accept();
}
```

На форме расположены checkbox (симулировать процесс аутентификации) и две кнопки "применить"(applyButton) и "закрыть"(closeButton).

Из основного окна вызывает вот так:

```
Authentication dialog(this);
if(dialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
{
    //значит пользователь нажал кнопку "применить"

    bool authenticated  = dialog.getAuthenticated();
    qDebug() << "authenticated:" << authenticated;
} else
{
    //пользователь нажал "закрыть" или "крестик в углу"
}
```

Comment: После вызова accept() программа закрывается :/

Comment: Приведите код как Вы вызываете окно?

Comment: Authentication AuthWindow;
    AuthWindow.show();
    if(AuthWindow.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
    {
    string login=AuthWindow.login,password=AuthWindow.password;
    if(!TryLogin(login,password))
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    AuthWindow.close();
    user(login, password);
    }else exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

Comment: Дополните свой первоначальный ответ.

Comment: `в C++ обычно принято название классов писать с большой буквы, а название переменных с маленькой` — Boost и стандартная библиотека шаблонов (STL) посмотрели на вас с укором.

Comment: С другой стороны: Qt, Juce, ACE, TinyXml